# Why I have a wrong result in C after storing a division of integers in a floating variable?

Tags: c, gcc

I am working with STM32 and GCC Compiler and I make the following division:

```
uint8_t w, h;
w=2;
h=5;
float test = (w * h) / 8;
```

and the result is `test=1`

Why am I wrong? I cannot understand this behavior.

Could someone explain me the reason?

Answer (score 3):

`(w * h) / 8` is an integer expression with an integer result.

The assignment to `float` is an implicit cast, but will not recover the lost fractional part.

You can make the division a floating point expression by ensuring that at least one of the operands is floating point:

```
float test = (w * h) / 8.0f ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following modification if you want to get the correct result:

```
uint8_t w, h;
w = 2;
h = 5;
float test = (float)(w * h) / 8;
```

If you divide integers, you get an integer as a result.